# I have a trouble with overflow

Tags: vba

I don't understand why 2 of my codes have overflow error

```
Sub varr3_1()
    
    Dim x As Single
    Dim y As Single
    For x = 1 To 2 Step 0.2
        y = Sqr((x - 1) / (x + 1))
        Debug.Print x, y
    Next x
End Sub
```

```
Sub varr3_3()
    
    Dim x As Single
    Dim z As Double
    For x = 3 To 8 Step 0.9
        z = 2
        While (z > 1)
        z = Log(x) + Tan(2 * x)
        Debug.Print z
        Wend
    Next x
End Sub
```

I tried to change Single to Integer and so on but there is still a problem [image]

Comment: In `varr3_1` you are (probably unexpectedly) printing the results for `x` being equal to `1` through `1.8`. To also get the result for `x = 2`, instead of the `Single` data type, use the `Double` data type. In `varr3_3`, you obviously did something wrong. Could you share the mathematical formula(e) `varr3_3` should be based on?

Comment: CPUs are optimised for `Double` and 32/64 bit integers. VBA uses 16 bit names for datatypes. So a VBA Integer is 16 bit. In VBA a 32 bit integer is called a `long`. `Single` is an old floating point datatype. So always `as Double` or `as Long`.

Comment: X -1 = 0.sqr(0/2) is.....mm

Answer (score 0):

The first sub Var3_1() works fine for me.
The second sub gets stuck in an endless loop on the second iteration of x. The value of z = 19.86... which will always be greater than 1 so the While/Wend loop never exits thus resulting in an eventual overflow.